# iOS fairplay throws unknown error 42650

Tags: ios, avplayer, fairplay

I am trying to play a [FairPlay DRM stream](https://developer.apple.com/streaming/fps/) on `AVPlayer` on an iPhone 5S running iOS 10.2.1 but its giving unknown error with **code 42650**. I get the same error on tvOS 10.1.1.

What does this error code 42650 mean?

Comment: Post more information about your OS

Comment: Its iPhone OS version 10.2.1 . Running on iPhone 5S. Fairplay DRM content.

Comment: Even on TVOS 10.1.1 it gives same error.

Comment: I had the same error on iOS 12.1.4, waited for a while and when I tried to play again it worked. Maybe it's an error related to the server or the connection?

Answer (score 1):

I've received Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-42650 when I call makeStreamingContentKeyRequestData()/streamingContentKeyRequestData() with a corrupt certificate.

This on iOS 13.3.1 and iOS 12.4